# How to display Time in MVC4 using jquery or Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

My Model

```
   [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
    [Display(Name = "TimeOfDrAvailablity")]
    public System.DateTime TimeOfDrAvailablity { get; set; }
```

create view

```
  <p>
<input class="disableTimeRangesExample" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
            $('.disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker({
                'disableTimeRanges': [
                    ['1am', '2am'],
                    ['3am', '4:01am']
                ]
            });
        });
</script>
```

I Don't know where i am wrong..please suggest any help...
i m trying following tutorial..http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/
also tell me how to add id and class using model

```
  <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor((model => model.TimeOfDrAvailablity), 
                         new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
     @Html.EditorFor((model => model.TimeOfDrAvailablity), 
                         new { @class = "disableTimeRangesExample", type = "date" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeOfDrAvailablity)
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use

```
@Html.EditorFor((model => model.TimeOfDrAvailablity), 
                         new { @class = "disableTimeRangesExample", type = "date" })
```

in order to apply classes and types to an `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply html attributes to `EditorFor()` in MVC-4 (you need at least MVC-5.1). Just use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TimeOfDrAvailablity)
```

which will add the `type="time"` attribute for you (because you have applied the `[DataType(DataType.Time)]` attribute, and then use its `id` attribute to attach the plugin

```
$('#TimeOfDrAvailablity').timepicker({ ....
```

Side note: Since you using a jquery plugin, the `[DataType(DataType.Time)]` and `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]` attributes are not necessary since they are only used to render the browsers HTML5 time picker implementation. It could be just

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeOfDrAvailablity)
```

in which case you could add a class name using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeOfDrAvailablity, new { @class = "disableTimeRangesExample" })
```