# How to Add Time in MVC4 using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc4. I want to add time in mvc4 using Jquery .

I am following  this tutorial http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/

Appointment Model

```
[DataType(DataType. DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "TimeOfDrAvailablity")]
public DateTime TimeOfDrAvailablity { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Create View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor((model => model.Date), new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
</div>

<div class="input-group clockpicker" data-placement="left" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:14">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

but I want to use something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeOfDrAvailablity, new { @class = " clockpicker", type = "date" })
</div>
```

Script

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datefield").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true, minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
       });
    </script>
}
```

In my Layout

```
<!--clockpicker -->
@Styles.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/css/bootstrap-theme.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/css/bootstrap.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/css/bootstrap.min.css")

<!--clockpicker -->
@Scripts.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/js/bootstrap.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/js/highlight.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/js/html5shiv.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/js/jquery.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Areas/Backend/clockpicker/js/respond.min.js")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: You can't add html attributes using `EditorFor()` with MVC-4 (you need add least MVC-5.1). And why are you adding `type="date"`? Just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.TimeOfDrAvailablity, new { @class = " clockpicker" })` And adding the `[DataType]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes to the property is a bit pointless if you are using a plugin

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke i try `@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.TimeOfDrAvailablity, new { @class = " clockpicker" })` but still it dosnt work out

Comment: NO it needs to be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.TimeOfDrAvailablity, new { @class = " clockpicker" })`. But in anycase, yout property `TimeOfDrAvailablity` is typeof `DateTime` but that plugin only generates values in the format `hh:mm:` which is not going to bind to your property anyway.

Comment: thanx for comment...but still its not working

Comment: You also have the scripts in the wrong order (jquery needs to be first). And why on earth would you include both the non-minified and minified versions of the same file.

Comment: Wow, I have just realized I pointed all this out in you [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626568/how-to-display-time-in-mvc4-using-jquery-or-bootstrap/29629235#29629235) and your still making all the same mistakes again!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank for help.my mistake was unordered of js ans css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer may be it will help others.

1. i added  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in `<head>` tag.
2. `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` before `<body>`.

3.also delete dublicate `jquery.js` files.

4.last but very important **Order Of Jquery file**.i.e`jquery.js` should be loaded first and then `jquery-ui.js`.